# How to create map and a div near it fixed, so that content of div move with scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some houses in right div and I have a map in left side and I want to create something like the below addresss :
https://www.hometogo.com/search/5460aea1318a0?campaign=widget/all/a/wimdu/5460aea1318a0&w-message=1&persons=2&arrival=2018-10-10&duration=9

I want my map become fixed like the top link and should be able to see more houses with scroll
and I dont want the div with class showResultSearch have a scroll.how I can do it ?

```js
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('searchMap'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

```css
.searchContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.searchResults {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.showResultSearch {
  clear: both;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.searchMap {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 600px;
}

#searchMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.specialOffer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="searchContainer">
  <div class="searchResults">

    <div class="showResultSearch">
      <div class="row" id="houses">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <figure class="specialOffer">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img src="Images/house1.jpg" />
            </a>
            <figcaption>
              <div class="title-house">
                <a href="#" class="house-name">
                  <h3>house1 </h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <figure class="specialOffer">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img src="Images/house2.jpg" />
            </a>
            <figcaption>
              <div class="title-house">
                <a href="#" class="house-name">
                  <h3>house2 </h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <figure class="specialOffer">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img src="Images/house1.jpg" />
            </a>
            <figcaption>
              <div class="title-house">
                <a href="#" class="house-name">
                  <h3>house3 </h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <figure class="specialOffer">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img src="Images/house1.jpg" />
            </a>
            <figcaption>
              <div class="title-house">
                <a href="#" class="house-name">
                  <h3>house4 </h3>
                </a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="searchMap">
    <div id="searchMap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: can you please update your fiddle, I think it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Throw out position: relative out of .searchContainer and add display: flex.

Set position: fixed on #searchMap

Works fine as far as I understand your question.
As for scrollbars try to work with overflows (overflow: hidden) or with widths and heights.